# How do I override OnDraw of ImageView when using XML layout?

Tags: android, image, dynamic, overriding, imageview

I'm new to Android, but frustrated with what seems a basic question, so apologies if this is a stupid question...

I need to override onDraw for an ImageView (to draw dots on the image), I can do this, but I also want to add a button to the screen.

I've created an ImageView in my code and setContentView(myImageView). But how do I add a button under this image? Ideally, I'd like to call everything from XML, but I don't think I'd be able to override onDraw for the image if I did that?

Perhaps I could create a Layout in the code, then add the image and button dynamically to my layout, then setContentView(layout)?

Thanks

Comment: @Chriss: No offence meant but it sounds like you should try some of the tutorials here... http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom view, override the onDraw() method and use it from XML:

```
<com.my.package.MyCustomView />
```